# DC Thump-like noise with Isolation Transformer

Tags: audio, transformer

I put an isolation transformer inline with my audio (unbalanced 2 channel audio; with L, R, signal Ground).

It still makes noise when plugging the auxiliary cord in (kind of like 2 thumping noises) or when I tap the aux plug onto a piece of grounded metal. All other static like noises are gone though.

I thought the isolation transformer gets rid of the dc thump? What could this noise be from?
Could it be contact bounce?

Please tell me if anything needs clarification!

---

**Have tried:**

I have tried another isolation transformer that I made myself for fun, it got rid of ALL DC thump-like noises including when plugging the auxiliary cord in or when I tap the aux plug onto a piece of grounded metal. That transformer was not good at transmitting a big chunk of the lower frequencies of human hearing so it is not a viable choice.

Comment: Are you using a 1/4" jack, or an XLR connector? Perhaps you're shorting the input as you plug it in. Do you have a bleeder resistor to drain the first input capacitor?

Comment: Is there a DC component on the original unbalanced audio?

Comment: @tomnexus 1/8" jack with unbalanced audio. I will try to check for shorts... I also do not have a capacitor in my isolation transformer circuit yet, I just have my transformers at the moment. I did not know there is such a thing as a bleeder resistor either...

Comment: @BrianDrummond The only DC component there would be the input device i think? and thats what I am trying to isolate with the transformers.

Comment: You *always* short a 1/4" jack as you plug it in. And before that you connect the tip of the cable to the ground of the jack. Think of plugging in an electric guitar, it always pops a but. I'd recommend another connector, maybe an XLR / Cannon, that doesn't short things together.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question : is there a DC VOLTAGE on the input signal? You need a coupling capacitor to block that : putting DC across a transformer is bad, and also will produce a thump when you plug the transformer in.

Comment: @tomnexus i think i get what you mean... i dont know how to search to learn more about that lol

Comment: @BrianDrummond uhhh... i thought i have the DC isolated with my isolation transformer.... the transformers are suppose to only let ac signal through right? they are 1:1 transformers. I also am not plugging the transformers anywhere, they are plugged inline in the circuit already and are supposed to be a relatively permanent part of it. i also MADE another isolation transformer by hand before this revision and I computer oscilloscoped that one and it showed it was working as expected (no dc signal going through with them vs. some dc without them).

Comment: oh yea, and i knew what a bleeder resistor was =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a couple of reasons why you are getting a DC thump when connecting the transformer to the source or destination.

1) The output has a permanent DC offset present.  This is often a common problem with older analog audio equipment having a bipolar power supply - the bipolar supply allows all of the audio stages to be DC-coupled and offset voltage at one or more of the op-amp stages is propagated through to the output.

This type of offset voltage is usually quite low (several mV) but can get to be quite high if there is a failure of some sort within the equipment.

The way to fix this problem is to measure the DC offset so that you know the polarity, then install a good quality electrolytic capacitor in series with the signal and a bleeder resistor from the signal to ground (to charge the capacitor).

2) The equipment runs from a single supply rail and the output is capacitively-coupled *without* a bleed resistor to ground at the output jack.  This is a common problem with older, inexpensive consumer-grade equipment.

The problem is that the capacitor charge bleeds to zero when nothing is connected to the jack, and thus there is a sizeable DC offset present at the jack.  When you connect your load to the jack, the capacitor charges and the DC offset settles down at zero.  But there is a thump while the capacitor is charging.

The way to fix this problem is to add a discharge resistor in parallel with the jack so that the capacitor charges immediately when power is applied.  This resistor would normally be somewhere between 10k - 100k.

Do note that with this type of equipment, you will *always* get a DC thump when the equipment is being turned ON and may get a thump when it is turned OFF.

Comment: super helpful. thank you.
so if i have it as such: InputDevice -> InputJack -> CoilsOnTransformer | CoilsOnTransformer -> Amp/Speakers. With L,R,SignalGround wires. If my problem was #1, where would I put the capacitors? L,R? or all? If my problem was just #2, what would I be connecting the bleed resistors to? L-sG and R-sG? does it still apply when i have a common signal ground?

Comment: oh yeah, and also the cap and resistor would go between the CoilsOnTransformer -> Amp/Speakers?